# Flutter releasing the web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm trying to build a flutter web. after releasing the app enter the application folder to the address:

> ** myapp\build\web **

But when I open the `(index.html)` file, nothing is displayed :(
How can I use this file?

Comment: when running ```flutter build web``` cmd , is there an error occur?

Comment: No Without any error